# Copy macOS installation to second partition

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition, bootable-disk

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 on the 4th partition of my HDD. The partitions in order:

> `Partition 1, 280 MB: EFI`
>   `Partition 2, 22 GB: Storage 1`
>   `Partition 3, 186 GB: Storage 2`
>   `Partition 4, 110 GB: Macintosh HD`
>   `Partition 5, 600 MB: Recovery HD`

Storage 2 has 102 GB available, and Macintosh HD only has 66 GB used, so space is not a problem. I need to copy my macOS installation from Macintosh HD to Storage 2, so that I can delete Macintosh HD, and expand Storage 2 to include the now free 110 GB. The catch is that I need to preserve *all* the data on both partitions while copying the installation. User data, system preferences, my command line package managers, *everything*. Plus in doing so I need Storage 2 to become a bootable volume. Neither reinstalling macOS, wiping Storage 2 for a restore from Macintosh HD, or wiping and repartitioning the whole disk are options here (I don't have a spare drive large enough to store all that data on.).

I have tried a simple `sudo cp -R / /Volumes/Storage\ 2/` (from in-OS that is), but some files have read/copy permissions denied even to the root user, and that's with SIP *off*. So... anyone have any ideas? I'm not partial to either the GUI or command line, so long as it gets the job done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand your questing and I don't have an answer, but IMHO you can try to move 40 Gb of non-system files (that are movable) to Storage 2, cleanup Storage 1 (also by moving them to Storage 2), clone Macintosh HD to Storage 1. Then boot from Storage 1 and merge those 3 partitions to one single. And even if you will boot from Storage 1, I still not sure that you will be able to repartition Storage 2 and Macintosh HD because unexpected and unexplained partition errors is a really often case in my experience.

Comment: @toma While your suggestion would likely work, I should add that Storage 1 is currently reserved for other things, and needs to remain a separate partition. See, my Recovery HD partition hasn't worked since Mavericks, and I'd been having to use an installer USB as a recovery drive. Since I've decided to clone the installer USB for each new macOS release to Storage 1, and use it as an installer/recovery combo. I have potentially found an answer in the bash program `ditto`, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to achieve what I needed using the following procedure:

> 1.) `sudo -i`
>   *Enter root shell*
>
> 2.) `mkdir /Volumes/Storage\ 2/Data/ && mv /Volumes/Storage\ 2/* /Volumes/Storage\ 2/Data/ && mv /Volumes/Storage\ 2/.* /Volumes/Storage\ 2/Data/`
>   *This relocated all my data on the target volume to a separate folder*
>
> 3.) `ditto -X -V --nocache / /Volumes/Storage\ 2/`
>   *This copied all files and symlinks from my boot volume to the volume "Storage 2", and made "Storage 2" bootable in the process.*
>
> 4.) `reboot` > Storage 2
>   *Booted into Storage 2*
>
> 5.) `diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Macintosh\ HD disk0s4`
>   *Deleting the old boot volume, and leaving free space in its place*
>
> 6.) `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 296G`
>   *Expand the new boot volume to include the free space I just made*
>
> 7.) `diskutil rename disk0s3 Macintosh\ HD`
>   *Renamed new boot volume to match old one*
>
> 8.) `diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" Recovery\ HD disk0s5`
>   *Delete faulty recovery partition*
>
> 9.) `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 296.6G`
>   *Expand new boot volume to include rest of free space*

Since performing this half of my two-part project the partition scheme now looks like this:

> Partition 1, 210 MB: EFI
>   Partition 2, 22 GB: Storage 1
>   Partition 3, 297 GB: Macintosh HD

Hopefully this will be helpful for anyone else who needs to move their macOS installation to another partition without losing any data, or anyone who needs to make a bootable backup of their system before performing a potentially dangerous operation.

Now that this part is done, I just need to figure out how to turn "Storage 1" into a bootable installer partition.

Comment: step 5, 6, 8 and 9 can be summarized as `diskutil mergePartitions disk0s3 disk0s5`.

Comment: @klanomath They could indeed, however I prefer to be verbose in my explanations, that way someone with less experience managing disks from the command line can still follow this procedure.